# Laravel 5.1 Querying Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

Learning Laravel by building a stock portfolio app. Have models for Users, Accounts, Stocks, Options, and Transactions. I believe I have the relationships set up properly.

Question is how do I get a Users->Account->Transactions. I'm sure I could just do something in query builder but I was hoping for a more "eloquent" approach.

User

```
public function accounts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Account');
}

public function stocks()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stock');
}

public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option');
}

public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
}
```

Account

```
class Account extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'name',
        'broker'

    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function stocks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Stock');
    }

    public function options()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Option');
    }

    public function transactions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction');
    }
```

Transaction

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = 
    [
        'type',
        'account_id',
        'transaction_date',
        'quantity',
        'stock_id',
        'option_id',
        'amount',
        'description'

    ];


    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function stock()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Stock');
    }

    public function option()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Option');
    }

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
    }

    public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Account', 'App\User');
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I guess I would be looking for a total amount for each account a user may have. (User can have many accounts and each account would have many transactions, stocks and options.)

Thanks for any help or at least letting me know if I am going down the right road!!

Comment: It seems like the query builder approach would be the way to go.  Otherwise, you will end up loading each `Transaction` object into memory, when really all you need is an aggregate value per account.

Comment: I was kinda afraid of that. The idea was to have a page listing all of a users separate accounts with a balance and then click the account to open a page that listed all of the transactions. Same for a particular stock. you could see the total amount of stock for a user then split by account then list of transactions that involved that stock separated in each individual account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$user` is a User object then `$user->accounts` is a collection of Eloquent models

You can load all of the accounts and their transactions with eager loading:

```
$user->load([
    'accounts',
    'accounts.transactions',
]);
```

But  `$user->accounts->transactions` isn't something you can do because "transactions" is a relation on each **individual** `Account` object, not on the **collection** of account objects. So to get the transactions you'd loop through each account:

```
foreach ($user->accounts as $account) {
    // do something with $account->transactions;
}
```

I highly don't recommend doing this, as @alexw mentioned in his comment, Eloquent objects are pretty large and having x many x many is an exponentially large amount of data you're loading into memory. But generally, that's how you'd access relations of relations.

**You're better off using the query builder**

The good news is that relations can make querying really easy! For example, you could do something like this instead:

**Note: in Laravel 5.2, the `lists` method has been replaced with `pluck`**

```
$user->load(['accounts']);

foreach ($user->accounts as $account) {
    $amounts = $account->transactions()->lists('amount');
    $total = $amounts->sum();

    // - or -

    $query = $account->transactions()
        ->select(\DB::raw('SUM(amount) AS total'))
        ->first();
    $total = $query->total;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both for the help. I will take your suggestion. The last example you gave returned a total and showed me how to . Just so i understand the process, if I were to use the eager loading example, is it loading all the data for just that user? or loading for all the users and their transactions and then just filtering out the requested user. My point being that if it just returns a single user then the data may not be that large but if it puts all the users into memory then pulls out the requested user that could definitely be huge.  Thank you both again!!

Comment: @BrioDev it just loads the data for that one user. You say it "may not be that large" but always think of long term and edge cases. Maybe 2 years from now that *will* be a lot of data, even just for one user. Or maybe you have a user who does an obscene number of transactions.

Comment: Absolutely right. Thank you very much. My next mountain is to learn React and was going to use it for updating the prices and sorting views etc. I thought maybe sending all the data to it as one chunk may be the way to go and then let it sort everything out as far as the views go. Smaller bits of JSON I'm sure will be easier to manage. Still a lot to learn and it's good to know that there are people like you that are willing to help!! Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. In addition to accepting my answer, it'd be great if you gave me a vote up as well :)